# Does the 2-step verification solves the security problem

Tags: privacy, security

I want to ask if the recently well used 2-step verification does actually keep the online accounts safe. (by using a mobile phone) ?

1. Assuming access to phone stays on our concern.

   - What could be the case, that someone is able to get access over it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2-step verification (or 2-factor authentication) is a step above 1-factor authentication (just a password) because it requires the user to have access to something (generally, a specific cell phone) as well as know the password in order to log in to an account.

However, 2-factor verification does not eliminate any security concerns. Researchers have shown many times that 2-factor authentication can be compromised.   See these articles for some examples:

- [Google Security Vulnerability Allowed Two-Step Verification Bypass](https://www.informationweek.com/mobile/mobile-devices/google-security-vulnerability-allowed-two-step-verification-bypass/d/d-id/1108837) (InformationWeek)
- [Attackers Hit Weak Spots in 2-Factor Authentication](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/06/attackers-target-weak-spots-in-2-factor-authentication/) (KrebsOnSecurity)
- [Two-step verification in PayPal found vulnerable to hacking](https://www.techwalls.com/two-step-verification-paypal-found-vulnerable-hacking/) (TechWalls)

Using 2-step verification is more secure than not using it, by a long shot, but it can still be compromised. Like any other security method, you can always make something *more* secure, but you'll probably never make it *completely* secure.